# Expressions as replacement for Frontpage... How use it for the simple minded?

Tags: replace, frontpage

I have been using Frontpage to build three less than professional but usable  web pages since the late 90’s.  MS no longer makes Frontpage, but others told me Expressions was their replacement.  So, I purchased it, but it looks very complex and it does not indicate to me how I can use it to maintain our web sites as my new computer with Windows 7 leaves Frontpage in the disappearing XP era.

Could someone tell me how to gently learn and step into Expressions enough to use it to maintain and update our web sites?

Answer (score 0):

This book might help:
[Microsoft Expressions Visual QuickStart Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321492234)

Although it goes against every code/programmer part in me, if you must use it, start with building a simple site before editing your older sites with it.  Also, always, always back everything up prior to making any changes.